# Why does the outlet not have access to the model data?

Tags: ember.js

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gonvaled/XUnv9/1/) jsfiddle, where I am trying to render a node template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="node">
    <h1>Node template</h1>
    <p>The outlet comes here:</p>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

This should render a `node/index` or a `node/template1` template, depending on the route. And this is actually happening, but the templates are just showing empty data. Why is that?

(the data is fine, as can be seen in the `nodes` table template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the routes for node/index and node/template1 and then implement the model function so that it retrieves the model from the node resource as that is where you put your dynamic segment.

For example:

```
App.NodeTemplate1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('node');
  }
});

App.NodeIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('node');
  }
});
```

You can see it working in this version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ianpetzer/XajSS/#base

Answer (score 1):

`node/index` is an implicit child route of `node`. It doesn't have the model that is provided in the `NodeRoute`. You need to use `needs` to lookup the value in the `NodeIndexController`.

```
  App.NodeIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
      needs: 'node',
      contentBinding: 'controllers.node'
  });
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbptA/2/).